# Amazon SES - Avoid sending duplicated emails

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am reading about Amazon SES, and I find out that we can setup some alarms to pause sending emails if the bounce/complaint rate reaches a certain threshold we define, that's good, but I want also to setup another alarm to pause sending emails to spammed email addresses, let's say something an error happened in my service and it started sending emails to the same address multiple times, is there a way to avoid that, for example, if we tried to send the same email to an email address more than two times an alarm triggered and a lambda function executed to pause sending emails to the spammed email addresses until we fix the problem.

Comment: You would need something custom to do this.  SES does give you the ability to receive events if, for example, someone reports spam or you get a bounce.  But there isn't a duplicate email check.  I would turn it around and have a Lambda send emails.  It could check a RDS/DynamoDB table of recently sent emails for duplicates.  They could timeout after a period of time so that, for example, two duplicate emails in 1 minute is bad but in 1 day is ok.

Comment: thanks @stdunbar , that's what I was planning to do, but thought that maybe I find an easier way to do that directly from amazon.